# TIdHttp.Free takes 30 seconds

Tags: indy, indy10

Back on January 7th I updated to the latest version of Indy 10 (I know this is improper etiquette: but how can I tell in the source code the exact version I have?)  I recently found a situation where **TIDHttp.Free** was taking 30 seconds to execute.  I traced it to a situation where two **TIDHttp** objects were instantiated at the same time.  It was taking 30 seconds to free one, and then another 30 seconds to free the other.  I am pretty certain this was not occurring with the prior version of Indy 10.  Once I rewrote my code to free the first object before creating the second, everything worked fine (i.e. no 30 second delay).  The code below is a simplified example.  Although when I run this there is no delay.  Unfortunately I have the IdHttp objects embedded as member of other objects within my framework.  And for this reason it has been difficult to simulate using a simple application.

In the code below, my *fix* was to move the **idhttp1.free;** call before the TIdHttp.Create for the 2nd instance.

Any ideas?  I guess if need be I can try to simplify my implementation.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  idhttp1,idhttp2: TIDHttp;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1,IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  idhttp1 := tidhttp.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP1.reusesocket := rsTrue;
  idhttp1.handleredirects := True;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.reusesocket := rsTrue;
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
  idhttp1.get('https://www.google.com');


  idhttp2 := tidhttp.create(nil);
  idhttp2.handleredirects := True;
  IdHTTP2.reusesocket := rsTrue;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2.reusesocket := rsTrue;
  IdHTTP2.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket2;
  idhttp2.get('https://www.google.com');


  idhttp1.free;
  idhttp2.free;
  showmessage('done');
end;
```

Comment: Indy's version number is in the `IdVers.inc` file.  You can also right-click on any Indy component in the Form Designer at design-time to see the version number installed.

Comment: `TIdHTTP.Free()` should definitely not be taking 30 seconds to run. There is nothing special about having multiple `TIdHTTP` and `IOHandler` objects active at the same time.  They are independent of each other. But why are you using `ReuseSocket := rsTrue`?  It is not needed since you are not binding the sockets to any specific local port.  Also, you are leaking your `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` objects since you are not assigning an Owner to them and the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property does no take ownership.